# Get the result for every recursion or write it to a list. - genealogy

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have a genealogy.
Allot of the following statements:

```
man(thomas, 1960).
man(stefan, 1990).
man(leon, 2012).
woman(regine, 1965).
woman(nina, 1992).
born(thomas, 1960, regine, 1965, nina, 1992).
born(stefan, 1990, nina, 1992, leon, 2012).

born_2(Parent1, Bd1, Parent2, Bd2, Child, BdC) :- setof(t,(born(Parent1, Bd1, Parent2, Bd2, Child, BdC); born(Parent2, Bd2, Parent1, Bd1, Child, BdC)),_).
parent(Parent, BdP, Child, BdC) :- born_2(Parent, BdP, _, _, Child, BdC).
ancestor(Ancestor, BdA, Person, BdP) :- parent(Ancestor, BdA, Person, BdP), ancestor(P, Bd, Ancestor, BdA).
```

What i get with `?- ancestor(X, B, leon, 2012).` is just `false`.
When i put `write(Ancestor)` in the code it gaves me the right answer but in the wrong way: `stefanthomasreginenina`

The result i wish is:

```
?- ancestor(X, B, leon, 2012).
X = stefan ;
B = 1990 ;
X = nina ;
B = 1992;
X = thomas ;
B = 1960 ;
X = regine ;
B = 1965.
```

I have tried something like:

```
ancestor(Ancestor, BdA, Person, BdP) :- List=[], parent(Ancestor, BdA, Person, BdP), append(List, [Ancestor, BdA], List), ancestor(P, Bd, Ancestor, BdA).
```

But didn't get it to work.

What do i have to do?

*(this is not my original code. It's just a translated snipped. Spelling mistakes can come from the translation and are mostlikely not the problem i need a result for.)*

Comment: `write` doesn't automatically append a newline. Use `writeln` or put `nl` after the `write`: `write(Foo), nl`.

Comment: @mbratch : thanks for helping again. Found out the soultion by my self. Shame on me that i asked...

Comment: No shame. You asked in honesty. The only thing better than getting a solution to your problem is having figured it out yourself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn. I found the solution by my self...

There are two lines needed for ancestor:

```
ancestor(Ancestor, BdA, Person, BdP) :- parent(Ancestor, BdA, Person, BdP).
ancestor(Ancestor, BdA, Person, BdP) :- parent(Ancestor, BdA, Child, BdC), ancestor(Child, BdC, Person, BdP).
```

That gives me the right answer:

```
?- ancestor(X, B, leon, 2012).
X = stefan ;
B = 1990 ;
X = nina ;
B = 1992;
X = thomas ;
B = 1960 ;
X = regine ;
B = 1965.
```

found it on: http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/recursion.html at "recursion 4".

Comment: That's great! Glad you found it!